# Rxjava why Schedulers.trampoline() named 'trampoline'?

Tags: java, android, reactive-programming

in rxjava there are some Schedulers, just like io(),newThread()...,
there have one Scheduler named 'trampoline' ,this Scheduler used for: **Creates and returns a Scheduler that queues work on the current thread to be executed after the current work completes.**

I can't understand why this scheduler named 'trampoline' but not 'queue' (or other name like 'queue').

Do you have a same puzzle ?

Comment: `Creates and returns`, that's like trampoline

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you read this quote in the documentation

> All jobs that subscribes on trampoline() will be queued and executed one by one

Then you understand why, have you try to use a trampoline when you was a child two friends at the same time?, impossible right?

This post explain quite well the differences between io and trampoline https://medium.com/@I_Love_Coding/rxjava-schedulers-trampoline-use-cases-283f6649cbf#.9hsjmyto2

Comment: Though we can understand it once we see the explanation, I would say not everyone plays with the trampoline, including me. It would've been nicer to call it `Sequential`, `linear`, `queue`, `oneByOne`, which are all much obvious? Trampoline has way more complicated dynamics, i.e. could be used to mean 2 tasks which share the same thread pool/ thread but cannot run at the same time, but are taking turns each time.